# Arithmetic progressions of coprime natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking for a clean, elementary proof of the following basic number-theoretic result:
Let $n>0$ be a natural number. Then there is some natural number $b>0$ such that
$$1, b+1, 2b+1, \dots, nb+1$$ are all pairwise coprime.

Comment: Hint: choose $b=n!$, and explore when a prime $p$ can divide two terms of the form $jb+1$ and $kb+1$, splitting into cases when $p\le n$ and when $p>n$.

Comment: @GregMartin , thank you, I will consider this approach.